# Все инициализировал..возникает ошибка:Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта

Tags: c#, классы

```
var gridToXml=new ClassVivod[dataGridView1.Rows.Count];

    for (int i = 0; i < gridToXml.Count(); i++)
    {
        gridToXml[i].Key = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Key"].Value.ToString();
        gridToXml[i].ValueXML_1 = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Russian"].Value.ToString();
        gridToXml[i].ValueXML_2 = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[comboBox1.Text].Value.ToString();
    }
```

В момент присвоении возникает ошибка **ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта**

Comment: Вы, наверное, до этого программировали только на C++? В C# массив содержит не объекты, а ссылки на объекты, значит, его ещё надо инициализировать пустыми объектами.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если это весь код, то эта строка (как и последующие)

```
gridToXml[i].Key = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Key"].Value.ToString();
```

пытается присвоить свойству `Key` объекта, находящегося в `gridToXml[i]`, значение справа от знака равно. В этот момент, конечно, в `gridToXml[i]` нет ничего , кроме `null`, т.к. сначала объект надо инициализирвоать и поместить в `gridToXml[i]`:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < gridToXml.Count(); i++)
    {
        gridToXml[i] = new ClassVivod();
        ...
```

Comment: спасибо тебе!